# Why does the is_logged_in() method run in my CodeIgniter app?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't know why after I put exit; in the is_logged_in() function, the page
~/home/members became blank. If I comment exit; it can load the view page. p.s. $is_logged_in is not set yet.

```
<?php
    class Home extends CI_Controller {
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->is_logged_in();
        }

        function members() {}

        function is_logged_in() {
            $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

            if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true) {
                $data['main_content'] = 'login_failure';
                $this->load->view('inc/template', $data);
                //exit();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: It looks like the `is_logged_in()` method runs when the object is constructed. I don't know CI, but is this normal for CI controllers? Also, if `$is_logged_in` is not set, then your first clause in the `if()` will succeed, and so the `exit()` will be run.

Comment: use die instead page leaves blank coz there is nothing to display after exit use this see non-blank page if(!isset($is_login) || $is_login !=true)
   {
    //don;t echo the message from controller 
    echo "you don\'t have permission to access this page <a href="refernce for login page ">Login</a>";
     die();
   }

Comment: @halfer sorry my mistake.... never formatted code in comments

Comment: @C1pher: when editing, please do not swap following-line brace for same-line brace format. Both are legitimate code formatting styles. Thanks! (It's worth being careful with reformatting code - if code is substantially reformatted it is easy to mask the cause of a problem. I only do it if the presented code is completely unreadable).

Answer (score 1):

Page is blank because there is nothing to show after exit try this

```
public function is_login() {


      $is_login=$this->session->userdata('is_login');
      if(!isset($is_login) || $is_login !=true)
      {
        //don;t echo the message from controller 
        echo "you don\'t have permission to access this page <a href="reference to login page">Login</a>";
        die();
      }
}
```

The actual problem was your use of exit. When you load a view, its output is added to the Output class (system/core/Output.php). The final view data is then sent (echoed) to the browser by the line $OUT->_display(); found in system/core/CodeIgniter.php.

Since you tossed the exit in there, the script stops, and that display method is never called.

Comment: yes your code works. but my question is: if i don't put exit; there, the browser would load my view page with header content and footer. but if i put exit; after the loaded page, the browser is blank. if the code is exited, shouldn't it still show the loaded view page?

Comment: @Zoe  try die($this->load->view('myView', '', TRUE));

Comment: yes, it works partially(only loaded the header), coz it still needs to pass the $data['main_content'] to the view page. also can you explain why it would turn blank using my way? Thanks...

Comment: @Zoe `exit()` literally means you exit code execution for the rest of the file, meaning no code after the `exit()` is executed which is probably why you get a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

Without using function in `__construct` use in each and every method. **Load if only user valid, else it will load logging page**

In controller

```
<?php
    class Home extends CI_Controller {
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();

        }

        function index()
        {
           $result =  $this->Model_name->is_logged_in();
            if($result==1)
            {
                //valid user
                //$this->load->view("admin_panel");
            }
            else
            {
                //invalid user
                //$this->load->view("loging");
            }            
        }


    }
?>
```

in Model

```
<?php

    function is_logged_in()
    {
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

        if(!empty($is_logged_in))
        {
            $log = 1;
            return $log;

        }
        else
        {
            $log = 0;
            return $log;
        }
    }
```